# Rickey's Board Game Revenge?

Tags: story, cipher, treasure-hunt

Last night you had some friends over to play a board game. You ended up winning, but your friend Rickey, who always loses, left in a very bad mood.

The next day you wake up in a square room with doors in the middle of each the 4 walls. There is a compass and a note on the floor that says:

> Quinn beat me last week!
>   Walter beat me a couple of days ago!
>   Eric beat me when we played a couple of nights ago!
>   Ralph beats me every time he plays with us!
>   Tim likes to make me think I'm about to win, only to defeat me at the last minute.
>   You beat me last night!
>
> I'll show you all for beating me at board games over and over again! I have left you in a building that has a bunch of rooms that are all identical to the one you are in now. All of these rooms are aligned in a perfect grid. I have placed all of your no good friends in a room that is 11 rooms north and 11 rooms east of the room you are currently in. There is only one path that will lead you to them safely.  If you stray from that path, all of you will die a most horrible death. Lucky for you, I have left you instructions on how to get to them.
>
> Hope to never see you again,
>   Rickey, Board Game Loser

On the back of the note you find this:

> TN1D4LE1U2RS1DW1D3RN5LE2U9LS1L1DW

What is the path to that safely leads to your friends?

Answer (score 11):

No idea if this is correct or even on the right track, but

> Each number in the code precedes one of the letters U,D,L,R.  The other letters in the code, which don't follow a number, are N,E,W,S (and the leading T).  So perhaps the former indicate the number of rooms to pass through in a certain direction (relative to the way you're facing, as viewed from the top?) and the latter refer to turns in cardinal directions, e.g.:
>
>  - Turn North
>  - Move 1 room Down
>  - Move 4 rooms Left
>  - Turn East
>  - Move 1 room Up
>
>  etc.

Comment: This implies you have a compass? I can't imagine any other way to identify directions in a closed room with only doors ;)

Comment: I agree it doesn't make a ton of sense (nor would mixing cardinal and relative directions like that in the first place) but it's my best initial guess at what (U,D,L,R) and (N,E,W,S) would indicate.  :)

Comment: The compass directions go in clockwise order: N, E, S, W, N, E, S, W. Everything between them can be divided as [number][UDLR], and if there are two of those, the first one has U/D and the second has L/R: for example, between the first N and E is 1D 4L. My thoughts are that this represents a four-player game of something, with N/E/S/W representing the players.

Comment: (in format: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/29154995#29154995)

Comment: But still I have trouble identifying in what direction we have waken up if we don't have a compass ;)

Comment: This isn't it, but you did need to be able to tell which way is north, south ,east and west. I added in that you have a compass.

Answer (score 2):

Just a partial note:

> The new phrasing of the question points to an American keyboard as possibly important, since the first letters of the victorious opponents (Quinn... etc.) are **QWERTY**.
>  As SQLnoob pointed out, all of the letters in the string are either cardinal directions (N, S, E, W) or U (up), D (down), L (left), R (right), except the leading T.  Perhaps we need to start on the keyboard at T and follow the string somehow, but I can't seem to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what the U's and D's and L's mean since they don't jive well with cardinal directions, but what if...

> It's a set of instructions to Quinn, Walter, Eric, Ralph, Tim, and you (Luis? Donatello?)...
>  T: N1, D4
>  L: E1, U2
>  R: S1
>  D: W1, D3
>  R: N5
>  L: E2, U9
>  L: S1, L1
>  D...
>  W...